# HTML5 Canvas works and disappear when click anywhere

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, openlayers

In my following code, Canvas works perfectly and it shows on my map then it disappears when I tried to click anywhere.

I tried all the possible ways which submitted in (StackOverflow) here as solutions but no way, maybe my code has something error which causes that.

html code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.4.2/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

```
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.4.2/ol.js"></script>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>

    <button type="button" onclick="evt();">resolution</button>
```

js code:

```
image = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
      wrapX: false,
    url: image/{z}/{x}/{-y}.png'
  })
});

    map.addLayer(image);

    function evt() {
      var canvasContext = $('.ol-unselectable')[0].getContext('2d');
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var imgData = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      var imageWidth = imgData.width;
      var imageHeight = imgData.height;
      var pix = imgData.data;
      var l = pix.length;
      var i;
      for (i = 0; l > i; i += 4) {
        if (pix[i] >= 100 && pix[i] <= 200 && pix[i + 1] >= 100 && pix[i + 1] <= 200 && pix[i + 2] >= 100 && pix[i + 2] <= 200) {
          pix[i] = 255;
          pix[i + 1] = 0;
          pix[i + 2] = 0;
        }
      }
      canvasContext.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
    };
```

Comment: you miss,ol-unselectable this element

Comment: var canvasContext = $('.ol-unselectable')[0].getContext('2d');
in your html ,there should be an element which className contains ol-unselectable ,is it ?if that's true ,add it to the html

Comment: Or just... `$('#myCanvas')`?

Comment: (ol-unselectable) it's already in ol.js (openlayers) .. by the way, my code works correctly but the canvas disappear after show,

Comment: @xianshenglu avoid to edit code as snippet if this snippet produces an error that has not been discussed in the question. To OP please provide a real [mcve].

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for reminding

Comment: In a comment you said you use openlayers, nothing in the question body let us know about it. As others commenters poited out, your selector doesn't match the given markup: this is not reproducible. Now if I had to make a guess, I would say that your other script runs in a loop, which ticks every frame, and which will override your own drawing.

Comment: I am working on a uni project (WMS) and part of it, which I should implement is a loop over all the pixels in the map and got just certain values (e.g in my code between 100-200 and so on). Anyway, I will add the simple map code so it can give better idea about my code

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear and to clarify the problem, please recheck it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, for **Canvas on OpenLayers Map**, should add to the end of the function

```
map.on('postcompose', function(event){
                  evt(event.context);
              });
```

Thank you all..

Answer (score 0):

We have an incomplete view of your application so some of the following remarks are going to rely on assumptions.

You're selecting the first element with a class `.ol-unslectable`, which is presumably a HTML Canvas.

Then you're running through the pixels of that Canvas and changing colour values depending on whether a particular condition is met.

Then you're putting the pixels back onto the canvas you took them from.

There is much in your code which is unnecessary.

The following variables..

- `canvas`
- `imageWidth`
- `imageHeight`
- `red`
- `green`
- `blue`
- `x`
- `y`

... play no part in the function.

Your `imgData` variable holds the pixels of an image at the same dimensions as the `#myCanvas` elemnt, where more usually one would take those dimensions from the source image - after all it is these pixels which are being manipulated here.

If we remove all extraneous lines from the function it will look like this and still perform the same task.

```
/* 
  manipulate the pixels of $('.ol-unselectable')[0] 
*/
function evt (e) {
    var cnv = $('.ol-unselectable')[0],
        ctx = cnv.getContext('2d'),
        imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, cnv.width, cnv.height),
        pix = imgData.data,
        l = pix.length,
        i = 0;

    for (; i < l; i += 4) {
        [
            pix[i],
            pix[i + 1],
            pix[i + 2]
        ].every(function (val) {
            return val >= 100 && val <= 200;
        }) && (
            pix[i] = 255,
            pix[i + 1] = 0,
            pix[i + 2] = 0
        );
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
}
```

I would also suggest that you register an  `eventListener` to your button element rather than relying on an `onclick` HTML attribute.  Assign it a unique `id` ...

```
<button id="reso">resolution</button>
```

... and then register an `eventListener` once the DOM is ready (the JQuery way)...

```
$("#reso").on("click", evt);
```

Now, I'm aware that this may not be the help you were looking for, but the irregular effects you describe are not apparent from your example code.  I'm pretty sure you need those extra variables to do something - but from the question it isn't clear exactly what that 'something' might be.

Nonetheless, at least you now have a clean function that performs it's single task a little more efficiently.  ;)

- More on [Array.prototype.every @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).
- Canvas [Pixel manipulation @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)

Comment: thanks for the helpful clarification, and the good advice, I would start my comment that I really a beginner in programming and many things I still learn so it's difficult sometimes to define which is important and which is not. Regarding the variable that you mentioned (red, green, blue, x,y), they are just for me to log them in the console to check if my function work (theoretically well) or not

Comment: I got an idea (from many answers regarding similar question here),  that the problem causes by (ctx.putImageData)! do you think so? or just maybe because I am working with openlayers!

Comment: @User2010 perhaps this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427727/4746328) will help?  I don't know OpenLayers, but it seems it return a Canvas element when the `ol.map()` method is employed.  There are many questions here about copying an image - or a part of an image - from one HTML Canvas to another. (Don't forget to upvote my answer if you found it helpful  :D ).  BP